# Setting coordinate system of shapefile in R

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, r, shapefile

I created a shapefile (TESTPOLY) in R and set the projection using:

```
proj4string(TESTPOLY) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0")
```

when I read it into ArcMap and checked the properties, it said 'GCS_Unknown:

[image]

I checked the projection in R with:

```
crs(TESTPOLY)
```

And it returned:

> ```
> Coordinate Reference System:
> Deprecated Proj.4 representation: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
> WKT2 2019 representation:
> GEOGCRS["unknown",
>     DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
>         ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
>             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
>         ID["EPSG",6326]],
>     PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
>         ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
>         ID["EPSG",8901]],
>     CS[ellipsoidal,2],
>         AXIS["longitude",east,
>             ORDER[1],
>             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
>                 ID["EPSG",9122]]],
>         AXIS["latitude",north,
>             ORDER[2],
>             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
>                 ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
> ```

And even though it does seem to 'know' that I set the coordinate system to WGS 84, there still seems to be an aspect of the projection missing.

What have I neglected to do here to give this shapefile a proper projection?

Comment: There isn't an EPSG code for WGS 84 CRS with long/lat axis order, which may be the issue behind the 'warning'. If you set the axes to be lat/long then the EPSG code would be 4326.  However there is sufficient information in the WKT2 to define the CRS to allow the data to be  correctly portrayed.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what you've done and how you've constructed the polygons and how you've saved them to a shapefile. For example, this looks like you are using the `sp`, `rgdal` and maybe also `raster` packages, but you don't say. I'd strongly recommend you ditch this approach and look for a tutorial with the new `sf` package for spatial data.